# Android: how to create ksoap2 request?

Tags: java, android, soap, ksoap2, ksoap

I try to understand how use ksoap on Android. I have executed this ksoap request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:urn="urn:namespace">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:"method name">
        <urn:mode>"value"</urn:mode>
      </urn:method name>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

in entity part of HttpPost via AndroidHttpClient. I try do similar with ksoap:

```
 SoapObject root = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "method name");
    PropertyInfo pr = new PropertyInfo();
    mode.setName("mode");
    mode.setValue("value");
    root.addProperty(pr);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(root/*request*/);

    Log.d(TAG, envelope.toString());

    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
    try {
        transport.call(NAMESPACE.concat("/").concat("method name"), envelope);
        Object obj = (Entity) envelope.getResponse();
```

, but I have got an exception

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'SOAP-ENV:Server' faultstring: 'Processing Failure' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@44f7cab0
```

Could you please give me an example of this simple request to understand how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solutuion:**

```
     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;

    SoapObject root = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "method name");
    PropertyInfo mode = new PropertyInfo();
    mode.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
    mode.setName("mode");
    mode.setValue("value");
    mode.setType(String.class);
    root.addProperty (mode);
   //root.addProperty("mode", "value");
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(root/*request*/);

    Log.d(TAG, envelope.toString());

    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
    transport.debug = true;
    try {
        transport.call(NAMESPACE.concat("/").concat("Method of server"), envelope);
        Log.d(Qube.TAG, transport.requestDump);
        Log.d(Qube.TAG, transport.responseDump);
```

*order is important if you wnat to avoid types in xml